# Reloading without any action, toggle function is working but due to reload affects are vanished

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a php file with a form. The requirement is, when I press "Add New Organization" button I should show the organization form. But when I am doing that it happens but the page is being redirected to another page for no reason. I am pasting my code here. And also how do you debug such issues.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('I am being reloaded');
    // put your jQuery code here.
        $("#addNewOrg").click(function(){
            //alert('Hi from click event');
            $("#organization_form_in_resource").toggleClass("myHidden");
            //alert('I removed the hidden class');
        })
    });

    </script>

    <style>
        .myHidden {
            display : none;
        } 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <br /><br />
<div id="wrap" class="">

    <br /><br /><br />
    <!-- Begin Resource Form -->
    <div class="container" id="resource_form" >
        <div class="form_content">
          <h1 class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-10" align="justify"> Add a Resource </h1><br /><br /><br />

            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="insert_resource.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="resource_name" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                      <input type="textbox" class="form-control" id="resource_name" name="resource_name" placeholder="Name of the Resource" value="">
                    </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="org_select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Organization</label>
                     <div class="col-lg-10">
                       <select class="form-control" id="org_select" multiple="multiple" onclick="getOrganizations(this.value)">

                        </select>
                        <br />
                        <button  id="addNewOrg" name="addNewOrg" class="btn btn-default" >Add New Organization</button>
                         <div class="container myHidden" id="organization_form_in_resource" >
                            <div class="form_content">
                              <h1 class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-10" align="justify"> Add a Organization </h1><br /><br /><br />

                                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="insert_organization.php">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="organization_name" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Name</label>
                                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                                          <input type="textbox" class="form-control" id="organization_name" name="organization_name" placeholder="Name of the Organization" value="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      <!-- End of Organization Form -->
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="contact_select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Contact</label>
                     <div class="col-lg-10">
                       <select class="form-control" id="contact_select" multiple="multiple">

                        </select>

                     </div>
                 </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-3 ">
                        <button type="submit" id="submitResource" name="submitResource" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your jquery function to the below listed one

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                    console.log('I am being reloaded');
                // put your jQuery code here.
                    $("#addNewOrg").click(function(e){
                        //alert('Hi from click event');
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $("#organization_form_in_resource").toggleClass("myHidden");
                        //alert('I removed the hidden class');
                    })
                });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.It worked. Can you tell me what is the default action and why should the default be explicitly prevented.

Comment: when you click on the button it submits the form and and it triggers the action of the form, which is insert_resource.php. So either you have to move the button outside the form or you have to prevent the default action

Comment: shouldn't be the form action taking place only when the type of the button is 'submit'?